# GWT MVP implementation

Tags: java, gwt, mvp

I have few gwt mvp design related questions:

- Can we use event bus to switch views from one presenter to other via controller using custom event?
- If above is true, can the custom event (say changeViewEvent) contain name of next view, on the basis of which controller can take a decision, which presenter to show?
- Is it a good design to make views reusable(as a widget) in an application, though i don't agree with this, but will be happy if someone has any thing to mention in favor of this.

PS: all my views make use of custom widgets and there is no gwt specific widgets(buttons, checkbox etc...) in views.

Comment: Why this has been given -1, am asking a genuine question. I just want to know is it a good design decision or not. If not why and how it should be done ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do anything you want, but you have to consider the consequences. For example, if you switch views without creating a history event, a user may be thrown out of your app when a user hits a back button expecting to see the previous view.

I very much like the [Activities and Places](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideMvpActivitiesAndPlaces.html) design pattern. It takes care of all of the issues (history handling, bookmarks, tokens, etc.) You can also extend it to add animation effects when switching views on mobile devices - [mgwt](http://www.m-gwt.com/) does that.

Comment: You cannot do anything you want Andrei, there are other programmers who will have to read the code, the more it is specific, the more time it will take to understand it. Standard rules are good for that

Comment: @ZiedHamdi: This is a good point. I was not advocating using a totally custom solution. In fact, I recommended using a widely-accepted design pattern.

Answer (score -1):

> I have few gwt mvp design related questions :
>
> - Can we use event bus to switch views from one prsenter to other via    controller using custom event ?

- **This is a bad practice, unless you have real good reasons to do that. Since you're changing the view without having an impact on the url, you won't know what is a the state of a view at a choosen moment, you cannot get back to a previous view in an easy way, and finally, people will have difficulties reading the code, since you're out of the "standard".
  The only reference for you should be the url, you cannot assume data is loaded neither the applicatio is in a given state: each and any view may be the start of the navigation story for your users, so if you get information from any other source than the Place, you're probably doing wrong, especially if your source is an event. the only special case here is you don't want users to enter your app in a certain view state, so you 'impose' that another url is called before, and restrict the access to the view through an event starting from a given application state**

> - If above is true, can the custom event (say changeViewEvent) contain    name of next view, on the basis of which controller can
>     take a    decission, which prsenter to show ?

- **as said before, you're reinventing the wheel. It's far better to adapt to the existing mechanism that is well thought and covers the majority of cases. You can put a json formatter to tokenize your url while developing so it's not a nightmare to put variables in. And when you're done, create a nicer regular url format**

> - Is it a good design to make views reusable(as a widget) in an    application, though i don't agree with this, but will be happy if
>     someone has any thing to mention in favor of this.

- depends on what you call a View. if it's the activitie's view then youm might need that in very few cases, it's better to inherit a basic view and fork its children for each activity (even if the view does nothing, time will show it will evolve differently): this is better since the base view contains what is common without the specifics of each child activity.

  - Finally if you mean a composition of widgets when you say, a view, then you should definitely reuse them, it will make you obliged to improove your widgets and compositions to be in a constant improvement, this will heop you for the rest of the project, and maybe for other projects

Comment: i never said that am managing history, hence first 2 points you talked about are not valid.

Comment: If you didn't say it, that doesn't mean you don't need it (especially history!!! how can someone propose a web solution without history???). It even means less you will never need it (if you actually don't now). I'm talking about the architecture of MVP independently of your specific problem, your question was: "I have few gwt mvp design related questions" so I'm answering about design questions. Please consider the fact I wrote an extensive answer, that should make you happy instead of searching for "invalid" points. this is what happens when an expert talks to a proud beginner...

Comment: p.s: I'm here just to help people in trouble, because I once was in trouble when I was beginning. Surely i don't need your critics @Mohit, if you don't deserve the help I'll answer other people but you won't be of any impact on me, the only person you'll make in a worse situation is yourself